# Plotly R - Convert yaxis labels from numbers to defined times or numbers

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

You will see below that I have created a box plot in Plotly of a location using camera analytics.  I am trying to convert The y axis tick labels from 0 - 1400 to times.  So 0 would be 0000 or 00:00, 200 would be 0320 or 03:20, 400 would be 0640 or 06:40 and so on through 1400 that would be 2320 or 23:20.

The pattern is really the number divided by 60(minutes).

My code:

```
library('plotly')

df <- read.csv("BoxPlot.csv")

location_one <- df[df$Location == "location_one", ]

plot_ly(location_one, x = ~Date, y = ~Minutes, type = "box", name = 'Camera Activity') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~seven, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)'), 
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~seventeen, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty', 
            fillcolor='rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)', 
            line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)'),
            name = 'Business Hours') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~six,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,255,0.8)'),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~endsix,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty',
            fillcolor='rgba(255,0,255,0.4)',
            line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,255,0.8)'),
            name = 'Extended Business Hours') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~starteighteen,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,255,0.8)'),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~eighteen,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty',
            fillcolor='rgba(255,0,255,0.4)',
            line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,255,0.8)'),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(title = " ",
         xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
         yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed", 
                      title = "Count"),
         margin = list(b = 190, l = 50))
```

Here is an image so that you can see the layout:

[image: Box Plot]

Comment: Please provide a part of `df` through `dput` with which we would be able to run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this but I added a few things to the "yaxis" and it did the job:

```
layout(title = "location_one",
       xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
       yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed", 
                    title = "Time", 
                    tickmode = "array",
                    nticks = 8,
                    tickvals = c(0,200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400),
                    ticktext=c("00:00", "03:20", "06:40", "10:00", "13:20", "16:40", "20:00", "23:20")),
       margin = list(b = 190, l = 50))
```

[image: y-axis labels]